# How do I find the licensing agreement of a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube

Some YouTube videos are Creative Commons but I want to be able to discern which ones quickly without using the specific search feature. In short I want to see the licensing agreement per video at a glance.

Is there a place to do this on an individual video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the license information in the video's about section as illustrated below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If a video has been published with a CC-BY-SA license (for example) you could have to [manually check that in the description](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134960/is-it-possible-to-upload-cc-by-sa-licensed-works-on-youtube).