# Is it possible to upload CC-BY-SA licensed works on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, wikipedia

Is it actually possible? Has it been possible in the past? Did this option ever get discussed? Did google ever talk about it?

If not possible, one can't actually upload (or repost) a CC-BY-SA video on YouTube because being only CC-BY publishing available, that would constitute a copyright violation, am I right?

So, I can't upload on YouTube an original work derived from a CC-BY-SA publisher like Wikipedia, am I right?

(suggested additional tags: `cc-by-sa`, `creative-commons`, `licensing`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if that's the correct way to do it, but I am currently uploading CC-BY-SA content on YouTube specifying the video license in the video description.